# Python- Tkinter destroy() not working correctly with pops in loop

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have some labels which get periodically updated and often times some labels are removed. I do this with destroying the frame and  creating the frame again like:

```
self.list1 = [["test1", 0, 2, 5], ["test2", 3, 1, 4], ["test3", 4, 5 ,6], ["test4", 1, 4 ,6]]
self.label_wrapper = 0
def x(self):
    row = 0
    if self.label_wrapper != 0:
        #self.label_wrapper.grid_forget()
        self.label_wrapper.destroy()
    for i in self.list1:
        self.label_wrapper = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master = self.frame_info)
        self.label_wrapper.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='nwe')
        self.label_wrapper.columnconfigure((0,1,2,3), weight=1)
        for n, v in enumerate(i):
            text = v
            label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.label_wrapper, text=text)
            label1.grid(row = 0, column = n, sticky="nwe")
        row = row + 1
    self.list1.pop(0) #testing if item gets deleted from list and if old frame is deleted and a new one is made.
    self.after(10000, self.x)
```

After starting the program, the 4 items are neathly displayed.

```
#output start of program, first time executing function
["test1", 0, 2, 5] 
["test2", 3, 1, 4] 
["test3", 4, 5 ,6]
["test4", 1, 4 ,6]
```

After the first iteration the second item in the list gets deleted and a new frame is made which consists of 3 labels.

```
#output after second execution function:
["test2", 3, 1, 4]
["test3", 4, 5 ,6] 
["test4", 1, 4 ,6]
```

But after iterating over it again, the second item in the list does get deleted but the frame looks bugged. The frame is "refreshed" but now there are still 3 label in the frame. The second label(["test3", 4, 5 ,6]) seems to be appended to the list(its now the last label).

```
#output after third execution function:
["test3", 4, 5 ,6] 
["test4", 1, 4 ,6]
["test3", 4, 5 ,6]
```

After iterating over it again, 3 labels still remain in the frame with the following output:

```
#output after fourth execution function:
["test3", 4, 5 ,6] 
["test3", 4, 5 ,6]
["test3", 4, 5 ,6]
```

Clearly i'm missing something. I just do not se where it goes wrong. Does anybody spot where it goes wrong and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

The problem should be located with the destroy() part. if i do not add the destroy part then the output after 4 iterations looks like:

```
["test4", 1, 4 ,6]
["test4", 1, 4 ,6]
["test4", 1, 4 ,6]
["test4", 1, 4 ,6]
```

So for some reason the way i destroy the frame is not working properly. I have been scrolling and testing but have not found the solution. Any input would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to call `grid_forget` if you're also calling `destroy`. Once the widget has been destroyed, grid will naturally forget all about it.

Comment: thanks for the info, saw multiple things about it. I have tried it with and without and still the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried without `ctk`?

Comment: yes, same thing happens.

Comment: You are creating multiple instances of `CTkFrame` (4 initially, more each time your function is called again), and assigning *all* of them to `self.label_wrapper`.  Only the last value is kept, so you're only destroying one row, and overwriting the rest with new Frames.  You either need to append the Frames to a list so that you can destroy them all, or put your actual widgets into (probably unnamed) sub-Frames of a single `self.label_wrapper`.

Comment: thank you that was a very helpful comment. i appended the label_wrapper to a list and then looped through the list to destroy each one. works perfect now!